# Delete array elements to specific amount

Tags: php, arrays

I have array:

```
array('a','b','c','d','e');
```

And I want to trim it to **3** elements, so we end up with:

```
array('a','b','c');
```

What's the best practice to achieve this *with optimisation in mind*? My arrays are massive.

### What I've tried so far

1. `foreach()` loop through array and store the first 3 elements.
2. Count arrays and use `array_pop()`.

I feel there is a standard function or approach to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array-slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php), for example:

```
$data = array_slice($arr, 0, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't you tried

```
array_slice($input, 0, 3);
```

That is the easiest and the php's standard way